# ImageMagic convert from pdf to png. Шаблон имени на выходе

Tags: linux, imagemagick

Вопрос простой, но не могу найти ответа.

```
]$ convert pdffile.pdf extract.png
```

Извлекает все страницы из pdf до серии png файлов. Но проблема в том, что имена их идут

```
extract1.png
extract2.png
...
extract10.png
...
extract100.png
```

Что не очень удобно при просмотре.

Как задать шаблон имени, скажем, в три цифры 
001, 002, 010, и т.д. вместо одной 1, 2, 10, 100?

Comment: [`prename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e' -- *.png`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346917/110559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать вот такую опцию:

```
+adjoin  image_%02d.gif
```

Здесь *image_* - это начало названия выходных файлов, а %02d говорит программе о том, что в качестве окончания надо использовать 00, 01,...,10, 11...

Comment: Да, конечно! Очепятка...

Comment: в строке кода тоже...

Comment: convert +adjoin tplg_%02d.png Topologia.pdf tplg_.png ?

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor *tplg_.png ?* - в том смысле, что не получилось? Ну тогда - не знаю :-(